# Unique month-year combinations in excel/google spreadsheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, unique

I have one column (A) with dates and I want to create a column with unique month-year.

I could use the UNIQUE function but that requires creating an extra column (B) with:
`= DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1))` and the final column `= UNIQUE(B1:B)`

The question is, can I do it without creating the extra column?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of 2023, both GSheet and Excel have both the UNIQUE function and a BYROW function which is better defined and easier to understand than ARRAYFORMULA. Therefore I'm proposing a new solution that works in both products:

```
=unique(byrow(A:A; lambda(d; date(year(d); month(d); 1))))
```

Explanation: the BYROW() function loops over all the dates in the A column, and using the LAMBDA() it constructs a column of dates which replaces, for each date, the day of the month with 1. Then the UNIQUE() function takes only the unique dates.

*-- The answer below still works in GSheet, but is a little outdated and does not work in Excel --*

Wrap the date expression in an ARRAYFORMULA:

```
=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(YEAR(A1:A10), MONTH(A1:A10), 1))
```

There is no UNIQUE() function in Excel, it exists only in Google Sheets. You can simulate it using an INDEX/MATCH/COUNTIF scheme of formulas, but it's certainly not as simple as the solution above.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I need. Solution for Google sheets is enough for me.

Comment: I had to change `DATE(X, Y, Z)` to `DATE(X; Y; Z)` but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

When I used the answer from Feb 2018, I kept getting an odd date at the end of the list. It was because the blank cells were being taken into account.

I used FILTER to remove them. This gave me the unique month/year values

```
=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(YEAR(FILTER(A1:A10, A1:A10<>"")), MONTH(FILTER(A1:A10, A1:A10<>"")), 1)))
```